# How to redirect all new user requests to front page in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, servlets, spring-mvc

I want to secure (temporarily) my application by create front page with captcha and simple form. I suppose Spring Security is too complicated for this task. How can I catch all requests and check if some attribute in session is set? If it is set then all these `@RequestMapping` methods should be executed, otherwise redirect to one front page.

Comment: "Too complicated" from a users or from a developers perspective? If the latter is the case: Learn spring security and do it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a [handler interceptor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-handlermapping-interceptor) defined and applied to all the handlers. The example in that link shows you also how to perform the redirect. Also check the [mvc:interceptors](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-interceptors) for the Spring 3 - like configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply configure a [`Filter`](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html) for this